# How does emberfire maintain authentication sessions when restarting the app?

Tags: firebase, ember.js, firebase-authentication, emberfire

This is a very noobie question, but there is something I don't really understand.

Whenever I have an authenticated session with [emberfire](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/guide/authentication.md), I'm able to stay logged in, even if I do something like refresh the page or go hit the back button on my browser. The reason I find that strange is because Ember is a single page application. That means by hitting refresh I'm essentially restarting the app and I feel like I should be losing all my sessions and states. How is it then that my login state is preserved even when I refresh the page? Shouldn't my login information be lost when refreshing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Auth persists the auth state in web storage (localStorage/IndexedDB). This is the expected behavior in most apps. Many users expect their state to persist and not be forced to login each time even for single page applications. If you wish to persist your state per session (until the window is closed), sessionStorage is ideal for that. Firebase Auth team is looking into that.

Comment: Does that mean Firebase has something like a cookie to maintain the auth state of my machine?

Comment: Yeah, unlike a cookie though, this is stored only on the browser and not sent along the request to the server.